# How to get the current position of the dialog in win forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, position, drag

I have a dialog that I can drag it around the screen.When I close the dialog and open again. I want it to be shown in the last position it was before.

How can I save the last position of the dialog in win forms?

Comment: You can just show it again, you don't need to track it yourself. This assumes you are talking about opening the same instance of the form

Comment: Yes show it again. But how to show it in the same position it was before.

Comment: `myForm.Show()` or `ShowDialog()`

Comment: I have an initial position of the dialog, but when I drag it around. I want to save the last position of the dialog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample & dirty solution.

In solution we have two forms. Form1, Form2, and Settings static class.

```
public static class Settings
{
    public static int X = 0;
    public static int Y = 0;
}
```

Inside Form1 we have button1 that will be responsible to show Form2.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        frm.Location = new Point(Settings.X, Settings.Y);            
        frm.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Inside Form2 we have ClosingEvent Handler :

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.X = this.Location.X;
        Settings.Y = this.Location.Y;
    }
}
```

When Form2 is closing we are storing location to static Settings class. Later we are reading from this class X and Y position.

I hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1)  create your custom "dialog", which is basically `Windows.Forms.Form`.
    [FormStartPosition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formstartposition.aspx) property set to `Manual`.

2)  once created,  in its [OnClosing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onclosing(v=vs.110).aspx) event save its position somewhere from [Location](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414(v=vs.110).aspx) property

3)  next time you are going to show it, assign the value you've saved before.

Comment: Ok first I do this :   `_Form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;` 
2. How to get the position on closing   `_Form.Location =  ???  `

Comment: Yes, correct. `Form.Location` gets or sets form's upper-left corner *screen coordinates*.

Comment: So if I have a form called _form then to take its location I go with.
_form.Location = forM.Location;
I dont get it 
????

Comment: Before closing `_form`, save its location in event described above. Save in some other variable, no inside the form. Once you decide to create a new for, create it, and assign like `_form.Location=VARIABLE_SAVED_BEFORE`

Comment: So smth like this `var position = _form.Location;
                _form.Close();`  ?

Comment: @Besa: in OnClosing, you don't need to call _form.Close. It will be closed, once execution of that event is finished. Just save a location and that is.

Comment: _form.Close I added for other reasons.
but you are saying I should do smth like this:  `var position = _form.Location;` ?

Comment: yes, but `var position` should be a global variable, so it's not destroyed once form is closed.